# Conditions of diagonalizability of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$

(I) Suppose $A$ is diagonalizable, that is, there is a basis of $R^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. What can you say about $a, b, c$?

(II) Find conditions on $a,b,c$ so that $A$ is diagonalizable.

I found that the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=1,2$ are $<1,0,0>$ and $<b+ac,c,1>$. But there are only two linearly independent eigenvectors. Does this imply that $a,b,c$ are all zero?

Comment: Yes; I don't understand the difference between I and II here.

Comment: if $a= 0,$ then $dim(\ker(A-I)) = 2$  and $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $a = 0.$  here is the reason why. let us at look at the rank of $A- I = \pmatrix{0&a&b\\0&0&c\\0&0&1}.$ We have 
$$
\dim(\ker(A-I)) = 2 \iff \operatorname{rank}(A-I) = 1 \iff a = 0 
$$

Comment: +1 for a quick and simple answer. Kindly correct the typo. AT the end of implcations it should be $a=0$ (not $a=1$). But your main statement is correct.

Comment: @abel: could u plz explain the statement that $rank(A-I) = 1 $?...

Comment: @AR $\ker(A - \lambda I)$ is the dimension of the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$.  In order for $A$ to be diagonalizable, $A$ needs to have eigenspace for $1$ with dimension $2 = n-1$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan, thanks for spotting the typo. is fixed now.